# Angular 9 router redirect with ** not working correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, angular-universal

I have `**` path which should load `landing` if route `not found` , but instead it loads landing everytime for example www.page.com/contacts -> shows landing with www.page.com/contacts url, but contacts exists in my page, **how to load it only if route is not found ?**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: AppRoutes.admin,
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
 {
path: "**",
loadChildren: () => import('./public/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule),
 }
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.content}/:name`,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/contents/contents.module').then(m => m.ContentsModule),
  },

  {
    path: AppRoutes.cars,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/cars/cars.module').then(m => m.CarsModule),
  },
  {
    path: AppRoutes.private,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/tours/tours.module').then(m => m.ToursModule),
  },
  {
    path: AppRoutes.vehicles,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/carlist/carlist.module').then(m => m.CarlistModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.paymentsCancel}`,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/cancel/cancel.module').then(m => m.CancelModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.paymentsConfirm}`,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/success/success.module').then(m => m.SuccessModule),
  },

];
```

Is there any easy way to redirect all wrong url's to a specific module ? I mean if router url not found.

Comment: ** should be used as last mapping (to apply if nothing else applies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the wild card route at the bottom. The router checks for the first match it can find

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // ...
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.paymentsConfirm}`,
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/success/success.module').then(m => m.SuccessModule),
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule),
  }
];
```

This is explained in detail in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order)

> **Route order**
>
> The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. List routes with a static path first, followed by an empty path route, which matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and the Router selects it only if no other routes match first.

Answer (score 1):

You should move not found route at the end of the routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: AppRoutes.admin,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule),
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/landing/landing.module').then((m) => m.LandingModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.content}/:name`,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/contents/contents.module').then((m) => m.ContentsModule),
  },

  {
    path: AppRoutes.cars,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/cars/cars.module').then((m) => m.CarsModule),
  },
  {
    path: AppRoutes.private,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/tours/tours.module').then((m) => m.ToursModule),
  },
  {
    path: AppRoutes.vehicles,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/carlist/carlist.module').then((m) => m.CarlistModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.paymentsCancel}`,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/cancel/cancel.module').then((m) => m.CancelModule),
  },
  {
    path: `${AppRoutes.paymentsConfirm}`,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/success/success.module').then((m) => m.SuccessModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./public/landing/landing.module').then((m) => m.LandingModule),
  },
];
```